# Выделить определенную часть строки в текстовом файле и найти 8-ми битную XOR сумму всех символов

Tags: c++, строки, парсер

Недавно начала изучать с++, есть задание по обработке текстового файла такого вида:

```
RE002%%

RE002%%

RE002%%

RE002%%

RE002%%

RE004%on%

$GPGGA,124749.80,5543.3227107,N,03739.1366738,E,1,08,1.11,147.9635,M,14.4298,M,,*5C
$GPGSV,3,1,10,27,13,078,43,05,31,307,48,16,24,042,43,02,10,267,43*7D
$GPGSV,3,2,10,26,03,031,36,07,75,215,51,09,57,121,53,30,40,234,50*76
$GPGSV,3,3,10,23,29,117,46,04,36,114,46*70
$GPGGA,124749.90,5543.3227105,N,03739.1366737,E,1,08,1.11,147.9664,M,14.4298,M,,*54

RE005%off%
```

Нужно в каждой строке, начинающейся с "$GPGGA" или "$GPGSV", найти восьмибитную XOR-сумму всех символов между «$» и «*» сложить их и сравнить в 16-тиричной системе с последними двумя символами в строке. Для начала я решила выделить нужную часть строки и потом ее обрабатывать, на старом форуме с похожей задачей предложили справиться такими строчками кода:

```
firstSpace=s.find_first_of(" ");
secondSpace=s.find_first_of(" ",firstSpace+1);
fromSpaceToSpace=s.substr(s,firstSpace,secondSpace-firstSpace);
```

там человек выделял строку от пробела до пробела, я попробовала адаптировать под свой код, но ничего не работает, возможно будет лучше породить класс для этого, но уровень знаний мне не позволяет сделать это правильно

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>



using namespace std;




int main() {
string line, dollar, star, Checksum; 
float *t0 = NULL; 
int tount = 0;  
int k; 

    ifstream logs_("C:/Users/Olya/Desktop/LogGLO.txt"); 
    ofstream tout("outLOGTime.txt"); 
    ofstream pout("outLOGPot.txt"); 
    if (logs_.is_open()) 
    {
        while(getline(logs_,line))
        {   
            //line.find("RE004%on%")
            k = 0;

            if(line.substr(0,6) == "$GPGGA", "$GPGSV")
                dollar = line.find_first_of('$');
                star = line.find_first_of('*', dollar + 1);
                Checksum = line.substr(line, dollar, star - dollar);
                for (size_t i = 0; i < Checksumk.size(); i++)
                    {

                    }


                if (line.substr(0,6) == "$GPGSV") 
                {
                    for (size_t i = 0, N = 7; i < line.size(); i++)
                    {
                        if (line[i] == ',') k++;
                        if(k == N)
                        {
                        pout << line.substr(i+1,2) << endl;
                        if ((N += 4) > 19) break;
                        }
                    }

                }

        logs_.close(); 

        }
    }
    else 
        cout<<"File is not open"<<'\n';
    tout.close(); 
    pout.close(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Мне смешно, но я знаю откуда этот человек взял такой контрольный пример :) Советую всё-таки ещё немного подумать над задачей самой. Либо спросить на месте.

Comment: Одного `if(line.substr(0,6) == "$GPGGA", "$GPGSV")` достаточно чтоб в угол на горох поставить :) Вы понимаете, что эта запись эквивалентна `if("$GPGSV" != nullptr)`? Т.е. `if(true)`?

Comment: @MrBin Вы про пример с выделением строки от пробела до пробела? Или про задачу в общем?

Comment: @Harry скорей для меня достаточно 
dollar = line.find_first_of('$');

star = line.find_first_of('*', dollar + 1);

Checksum = line.substr(line, dollar, star - dollar);
Этих строк чтобы на горох в угол поставить, не понимаю, должны они вообще работать или нет..

Comment: Я про задачу :)

Comment: @MrBin Я была бы бесконечно благодарна, если бы вы мне подсказали, что я делаю не так..

Comment: @MrBin Если мы с вами говорим об одном и том же, то мне необходимо написать программу, которая по логам выведет от on до off  средний SNR и время работы

Comment: В общем случае вам достаточно построчно проверять наличие вначале вашего паттерна. А потом просто получать итераторы на символ за знаком доллара и на символ перед звездой. Потом прочитать последние 2 символа в шестнадцатеричной форме. Копировать в новое место и делать что вам душе угодно. Кода не будет, ибо не комментарий. Читать символы как шестнадцатеричные c++ умеет из коробки (Но только ASCII совместимые).

Comment: @MrBin получается мой код будет выглядеть примерно так?
```
for (auto it = line.dollar() ; it != line.star; it++)
{
}
```

Comment: Не сказал бы. В любом случае у вас **очень много** вариантов.